# Git commit locally then push later

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project where I am using Github. I am now working offline and so I cannot push the commits to Github.

Is there a way how I can still create commits locally (on the same branch) and then push all of the commits at a later date when I’m back online?

Comment: Read the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/doc). They are among the best docs i've ever read. Git was designed to do this specifically. Just commit when you feel like, and push when you feel like too.

Comment: git commit -m my local commit

some time later

git push

Comment: @JorgeBellón what section would I look for in there?

Comment: The introduction is good. It will take you 10 minutes, but they are worth it.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: @JorgeBellón So to my understanding, all I have to do is do `git commit -am “message”` after every change I want to commit and then just do `git push` when I am back online?

Comment: @iProgram don't use `-a` unless you want to commit everything.

Comment: So you mean that I would be able to commit everything and push at a later date with that command?

Comment: You upload everything with `git push`, yes. Therefore, you only need to be online when you want to push things to a remote server (in some cases you can even push to repositories in your local machine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 'git add', 'git commit' commands will work on your local repository. (can do it offline)
- 'git push' will push all your code to the remote master (once you are online)

When you are offline, you can add and commit your code. Once you are online you can do 'git push' command.

Comment: So you mean I can just `git commit` normally and then `git push` when I’m online?

Comment: Yes. I disconnected from network and did below :
x@xyz-pc:~/workspace$ git add x/y/test.java
x@xyz-pc:~/workspace/$ git commit -m "testing" x/y/test.java
 [xBranch4de0a88] testing
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)

Comment: You can push when offline too, but only if the remote is local.